# Intertemporal choice, Microeconomics

Tags: economics

I am struggling with this basic example. I understand how to calculate everything else but when I get to the point where I should take the equation together with the budget equation to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$, then I get puzzled. For some reason I am not able to find $c_1=105$ and $c_2=115.50$.
Could someone please help me to find it?

Where should I plug in this $c_2/c_1=1.1$?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $c_2=1.1c_1$ in $c_1 +\frac{c_2}{1.1} = 210$